# Can logstash perform statistical analysis on the data coming from filebeat？

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

OK,my problem is if it is possible to use logstash to perform statistical analysis on the collected log data.Now I have used filebeat to collect nginx logs into the es cluster and put the required labels on these logs.I plan to read these logs from the es cluster and write a program to make statistics on these logs, such as the traffic in a certain region for a period of time.Now, I want to know whether the logs collected by filebeat can be transferred to logstash for data statistics.

After a short period of research, I haven't found that logstash has this function. I hope you can help me.Thanks.

I want to know whether logstash can realize the functions I need

Comment: Logstash won't provide any such feature since its basically a log shipper and not a data store for analystics. Why do even want to use logstash for this when it can be easily visualized in Kibana using some graphs or table ?

Answer (score 0):

Logstash is basically ingests, transforms, and ships your data regardless of format or complexity. Derive structure from unstructured data with grok, decipher geo coordinates from IP addresses, anonymize or exclude sensitive fields, and ease overall processing. For I don't know your specific use case, but you can use Kibana for analyzing statistical data. You even don't need logstash if you have a node in your elasticsearch cluster with `ingest` node roles.